# Combinatorics: n people visit k exhibitions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-theorem

Edit: Excuse me, the numerator of the given solution should've been a rising factorial. That said, I still don't understand where it comes from?

The question is as follows :

> n friends visit k exhibitions, each person visits only 1 exhibition. Find the number of possibilities if
>
> b) Only the number of friends who goes to each exhibition matters. Neither the order nor who goes where matters.

Now, I have the solution which would be $$\frac{[n+1]^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} $$

But I don't really understand why that is so.
If I understand that correctly, that would be a *stars and bars* problem, but I don't seem to grasp the concept of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your solution would not give an integer for $n=4, k=3$

Comment: @Henry, that's a rising factorial in the numerator, not a power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's your basic stars and bars:  You have $n$ 'stars' (the friends), and $k-1$ bars to divide the friends into $k$ groups.

So, you have $n+k-1$ objects that you line up, and there are

$${n+k-1} \choose n$$

possible different ways to place the $n$ 'stars' in those $n+k-1$ slots.

This is not at all your formula though ...

Comment: Ohhhh so what you do with stars and bars is actually just permutation between the number of objects and (as in +) the number of 'boxes' (-1) in which you would place them? And the - 1 comes from the fact that it requires 1 less bar to subgroup them into K groups?

Comment: And yeah, my given solution should've been a rising factorial at the numerator, my bad... But in that case, are both formulas equal?

Comment: @user452306 Yes, the $k-1$ bars divide the $n$ stars into $k$ groups. So, for example, if you have $4$ stars ($*$) and $3$ bars, you could get: $***||*|$, which would represent $3$ friends going to exhibit $1$, $0$ to exhibit $2$, $1$ to exhibit $3$, and $0$ to exhibit $4$.  And so yes, it is just a matter of permutations, but you don't distinguish the stars from each other, and same with the bars.  Note that you can have multiple bars next to each other, and you can also have them at the end, all of which simply means that some exhibits would not be visited by any of the friends.

Comment: @user452306  But no, the formula you have is really not equivalent to mine ... in fact, as pointed out in the comments, your formula doesn;t even always give you whole numbers, so the formula given to you cannot be correct.

Comment: Hey thanks again for looking into it. I was looking for where they could've gotten that formula, and I've found a theorem 

> The number of *unordered lists* of k *not necessarily distinct* objects from a set of n objects is $\langle {n \choose k}\rangle = \frac{[n]^k}{k!} = {n+k-1 \choose k} = {n+k-1\choose n-1} , (n,k \in \Bbb N)$

(Where inside the angled brackets there shouldn't be normal round ones)

Comment: @user452306 Hmm, I am actually not sure what that notation with the angled brackets means ... and the square brackets in the second formula must mean something special as well, but again I don't know what ... though it would explain how they got to the formula you were given as someone thought those square brackets were just parentheses (which can't be so, because if you do that, you don't get whole numbers for various $n$ and $k$) ... where did you find this?

Comment: I'll be going forward using the formulas I got here, since I seem to understand them better. I found these on a script from a class I took some years ago, the script referenced these books: • R. Stanley: Enumerative Combinatorics, Volume I, Cambridge University Press
• S. Lipschutz, M. Lipson, Discrete Mathematics, Schaum’s outline
• J. Harris, J. Hirst, M. Mossinghoff: Combinatorics and Graph Theory, Springe, but I only used the script...

Answer (score 1):

Arranging $n$ stars and $k-1$ bars is a way of modeling this situation. Each arrangement of those $n+k-1$ symbols gives us a set of numbers of people to go to each exhibition. However, the result of that counting problem is:

$$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{n!(k-1)!}$$

Do we have a condition that each exhibition has to be attended by at least one friend? Do we even know that $n\geq k$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, first of, as is in my edit, the numerator should've been a rising factorial. Other than that, it's said that it's a large number of friends, so I assume it is in fact n>k.

Comment: That being said, I'm on my way home right now, I'll check that shortly! Thanks again

Comment: I'm not familiar with rising factorial. Looking at a definition, it appears that $[n+1]^{k-1}=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{n!}$. Thus, your answer is equivalent to both mine and the one by @Bram28.